# regex to find text inside first occurrence of tokens "[]"

Tags: php, regex

I'm grabbing a file via `file_get_contents($text_file)` that has a token in the beginning of the contents in the form...

```
[widget_my_widget]
```

The full contents of the file might be...

```
[widget_my_widget]
Here is the start of the text file. It may have [] brackets inside it,
but only the first occurrence denotes the token.
```

I'm looking for the regex to grab the text string inside the first occurrence of the brackets []. In this case, I'd want to return **widget_my_widget** and load it into my variable.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first captured group in `\[(.+?)\]` will match the string inside the square brackets.

In PHP you can use it like this:

```
if (preg_match('/\[(.+?)\]/', file_get_contents($text_file), $group)) {
    print $group[1];
}
```

At first occurance in this string (the file content), ignore the left square bracket, then match as little as possible, but up to (not including) the right square bracket.

Comment: Need to escape the second bracket too.

Comment: @jb, not sure what you mean by the second bracket, but in most regex implementations, `]` needs no escape (it doesn't hurt to escape it though).

Comment: @jb, @Bart Kiers Thanks. I'll escape it to avoid misunderstandings by computers or humans :-)

Comment: @Bart, and here I thought I knew a lot about Regex. I was referring to the `]`, but you are right, it doesn't have to be escaped. Learned something new today.

Comment: @Staffan, @jb, yeah, I often escape it too as to not confuse people. @jb, you probably know quite some regex, but there's always someone who knows more! (that goes for me too!) :)

Comment: @jb, @Bart Kiers In character classes it's even more. You only need to escape there if the engine can misunderstand. E.g. `[^]]` is correct. And of course `[.]` means literaly match dot.

Comment: @Bart, ain't that the truth :)

Answer (score 1):

I think Staffan's answer is mostly correct, but I have a minor correction and I think you may want to avoid the ^, or the string will have to start with a bracket and you said you just want the first instance. On to the code...

```
$str = ...

$pattern = '/\[([^\]+])\]/';
$n = preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
if ($n > 0) {
    $first_match = $matches[1];
    /// do stuff
}
```

My pattern looks a little confusing because brackets have special meaning, so I'll try to explain it... we're looking for a open bracket, then one or more characters that is not a closing bracket (in this context, the caret means "not"), then a closing bracket. The parenthesis are around the content we want to capture and the inner brackets are a character class. If that makes no sense, just ignore everything I just said.